# How to fetch part of url using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have created a dynamic div in that I use this variable and appended into one div:

```
vAlbum=vAlbum+"<a href='Preview.aspx' onclick=
'location.href=this.href?albumname="+result.Items[i].AlbumName+"'>"
```

How can I fetch `albumname` in Preview.aspx page with jQuery?

Comment: The easiest way is for the Preview.aspx to print it in a variable, i.e. `<script> var albumname = <% ... %>; </script>`

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery URL parser - https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Then it becomes:

```
var albumname = $.url().param("albumname");
```